# Detect mobile device minimizing

Tags: c#, windows-ce

Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional
.NET Framework 3.5
C#
Visual Studio 2008
Windows 7 Professional SP1

When the app runs on an MC75A, a small icon with an X (or OK if the form's MinimizeBox property is set false) is present at the top right in the "title bar". I have been advised that the app must terminate when that icon is pressed. I would like to establish an event handler to trigger on the press event, perform wrapup, and terminate the app (Application.Exit).

I do not know how to detect the icon press. Further, are there any suggestions on the best method to achieve shutdown?

TIA

Comment: Slightly an aside, but you have the "X" in the top right on a WinMo 6.5.3 device?  I would have thought on that OS it was in the bottom right.  More on topic, perhaps just check the form state = Minimized in the Resize event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (X) is a minimize.  It should minimize, not exit the app.  Follow expected platform behavior.  Clicking (ok) will close the Form, returning control back to whomever showed the Form.  If the caller was Application.Run(), then the app will terminate normally and this is the pattern you should be striving to achieve.  Closing a sub-form or dialog is again not expected behavior.

If you really must close the app, then just add this to the Form code:

```
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Again, I'd still disagree with this.  As a general rule, if your app is manually calling `Application.Exit()`, you have a design problem.

Comment: It isn't an issue with me as much as with the customer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Let me make a comment wrt the "design problem." This app is a work flow. At its core is a simple state machine that, like the Windows message loop, takes action based upon a user's input. There are 14 forms, from login to order complete. The user may leave and return to the "normal" flow at will. Within the framework of this problem, if I believe that the program needs to exit and return the user to the mobile OS, understand that is exactly what is needed.  
You know too little about the problem to make a comment like the one you did. Although I have not taken offense, maybe I should have.

Comment: I would posit that don't need to understand the busness problem at all to know what good software design is.  If your workflow needs to terminate that's fine.  It's doesn't mean you can't architect that scenario to exiting the primary form holding the message pump.  I simply pointed out two things - first, for platform consistency, only an (ok) should close the app.  Having otherwise will only confuse people.  And second, the correct way to exit an application is to close the Form passed to Application.Run. It's your app, do what you wish, I'm simply trying to help you follow a standard.

Comment: I'm sorry but standards are in the eye of the beholder. You are defending an indefensible position. Stating that you do not need to know anything about a business application, before making the comments that you are, is intellectual arrogance of the worst kind. I'm finished discussing this with you. You may be bright but you are not too cool.